# How can I account for AM/PM when using datetime.strptime?

Tags: python, datetime, time, python-datetime

I am trying to calculate the difference in minutes using datetime. The current implemntation fails because the program has no idea if it is PM or AM. For example the code below produces this output.

```
The difference in minutes between 2022-10-04 01:28:14 and 2022-10-04 10:28:14 is 540
```

This is wrong if the assumption is that the first time is 1 am in the morning and the second time is 10 pm at night. How can I check for am/pm? I have tried %H as well as %I

```
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S'
tstamp1 = datetime.strptime(firstRequestTime, fmt)
tstamp2 = datetime.strptime(secondRequestTime, fmt)
if tstamp1 > tstamp2:
     td = tstamp1 - tstamp2
else:
     td = tstamp2 - tstamp1
td_mins = int(round(td.total_seconds() / 60))
print(f"The difference in minutes between {tstamp1} and {tstamp2} is {td_mins}")
```

Comment: try adding `%p` to the format.

Comment: Noted... looking into that now. Thank you

Comment: please add information how `firstRequestTime` and `secondRequestTime` strings look like.

Comment: If you look at the output, you can see the strings, for example firstRequestTime is ```2022-10-04 01:28:14```

Comment: that wasn't clear to me from the question, sorry. The format looks pretty standard ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), normally, you have 24h clock with that (no am/pm). So parsing with `%H` (or directly use `datetime.fromisoformat`) does the trick.

Comment: Ill look into that champ. Thank you. I realized my requests do indicate whether its pm or am so it was just a meaning of adding the %p to my format!

Answer (score -1):

You can turn first the "naive" datetimes into "aware" ones adding timezone info.
So, the PM datetimes have 12 hours offset from the AM ones.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#aware-and-naive-objects

```
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S'
tstamp1 = datetime.strptime(firstRequestTime, fmt)
tstamp2 = datetime.strptime(secondRequestTime, fmt)

tstamp1 = tstamp1.replace(tzinfo=timedelta(hours=0))
tstamp2 = tstamp2.replace(tzinfo=timedelta(hours=12))


if tstamp1 > tstamp2:
     td = tstamp1 - tstamp2
else:
     td = tstamp2 - tstamp1
td_mins = int(round(td.total_seconds() / 60))
print(f"The difference in minutes between {tstamp1} and {tstamp2} is {td_mins}")
```

Comment: 12h format or 24h format has nothing to do with naive vs. aware datetime (tzinfo None or set).